# How to achieve Dependent Dropdown between Country and State in Django inside Admin Panel

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

So i have created a customer portal in django admin panel and i am not using any html because i will use the django default template throughout as of now.

But there is a slight issue which i am getting and that is not able to get dependent dropdown between the states and country.

Refer this image --> [image: City model in admin panel]

As you can see every city is popping up in the drop down.
I want the user to select country and then according to that country states should appear and then finally the user can manually enter the city name which he desires.

I have heard something related to ajax (js) in this scenario since i am a newbie i am not really good in javascript so can anyone help me on how to implement it or any other possible solutions for my problem. Thankyou <3

My code:

models.py

```
class Country(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    parent_id = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    name = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=255)
    status = models.CharField(null= True, choices=Status_Choices, max_length=11, default="--Select Status--") 
    added_by = models.IntegerField()
    updated_by = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    created_on = models.CharField(default=get_current_datetime_str , max_length=255)
    updated_on = models.CharField(default=get_current_datetime_str, max_length=255)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

   

class State(models.Model):
    Country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=255)
    status = models.CharField(null= True, choices=Status_Choices, max_length=11, default="--Select Status--") 
    added_by = models.IntegerField()
    updated_by = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    created_on = models.CharField(default=get_current_datetime_str , max_length=255)
    updated_on = models.CharField(default=get_current_datetime_str, max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    

class City(models.Model):
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=255)
    status = models.CharField(null= True, choices=Status_Choices, max_length=11, default="--Select Status--") 
    added_by = models.IntegerField()
    updated_by = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    created_on = models.CharField(default=get_current_datetime_str , max_length=255)
    updated_on = models.CharField(default=get_current_datetime_str, max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

---

forms.py

```
class CountryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Country
        fields = ['name']

    def clean_name(self):
        name = self.cleaned_data['name']
        if name == '--Select Country--':
            raise forms.ValidationError("Please select a valid country")
        return name

class StateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = State
        fields = ['name', 'Country']

class CityForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = City
        fields = ['name', 'state']
```

---

admin.py

```
    class CountryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ('parent_id', 'created_on', 'updated_on', 'added_by', 'updated_by')

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        user = request.user

        if user.is_authenticated:
            obj.added_by = user.id
        else:   
            ...


        if change:
            obj.updated_by = user.id

        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
        
admin.site.register(Country, CountryAdmin)


@admin.register(State)
class StateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ('parent_id', 'created_on', 'updated_on', 'added_by', 'updated_by')

    list_display = ('name', 'Country')

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        user = request.user

        if user.is_authenticated:
            obj.added_by = user.id
        else:   
            ...


        if change:
            obj.updated_by = user.id


        # Save the model instance
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
        



@admin.register(City)
class CityAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ('parent_id', 'created_on', 'updated_on', 'added_by', 'updated_by')
    list_display = ('name', 'state')
    verbose_name_plural = 'Locations'

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        user = request.user

        if user.is_authenticated:
            obj.added_by = user.id
        else:
            ...

        if change:
            obj.updated_by = user.id


        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your CityForm should should contain the following code:

```
 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['country'].queryset = Country.objects.none()

    if 'country' in self.data:
        try:
            country_id = int(self.data.get('country'))
            self.fields['country'].queryset = Country.objects.filter(country_id=country_id).order_by('name')
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            pass  # invalid input from the client; ignore and fallback to empty Country queryset
    elif self.instance.pk:
        self.fields['country'].queryset = self.instance.country.country_set.order_by('name')
```

More you can read in https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html